# JAX-WS: Two or more endpoints as ports of one Service and WSDL

Tags: web-services, binding, wsdl, jax-ws, endpoint

Is it possible to publish two or more JAX-WS Endpoint as WSDL:Port under single WSDL:Service to have a single wsdl with the below content?

```
<definitions ...>
    ...
    <service name="Airport">
        <port name="Cargo" binding="tns:CargoBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:9999/"/>
        </port>
        <port name="Civil" binding="tns:CivilBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:9999/"/>
        </port>        
    </service>
</definitions>
```

The idea is to merge two logically similar services under one. And I want to know how to achieve this using Endpoint.publish?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In WSDL definition, service is a collection of related endpoints, and the endpoint must have a unique address identified by a URI. In your code, the two endpoints' addresses are same.

You have to call `Endpoint.publish` multiple times for different port endpoints.
As your WSDL definition,

```
Cargo cargo = new CargoImpl(); // Cargo is endpoint interface
Endpoint.publish("http://hostname/service/cargo", cargo);
Civil civil = new CivilImpl();
Endpoint.publish("http://hostname/service/civil", civil);
```

Comment: Ok, maybe you know what is a solution for JAX-WS Endpoint to combine two or more instances under one WSDL?

Comment: Unfortunately this produces two separate WSDL's but not signle

Comment: @chaplean 'http://.../cargo?wsdl and http://.../civil?wsdl' these two WSDL which generated by jax-ws? Does it matter?